# Open a popup browser window to select a record

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I want to open a popup window on client PC where I will show records. The user will click on the selected row, and the popup window will disappear, but the parent Form on my page must get filled with the DB values related to the clicked row on the popup.

This is what I want to do. What is the right approach?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? In showing the records, or in communicating between thbe windows?

Comment: Stuck in both. First not able to open popup and not able to communicate also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to send back some response to your parent window from popup window.
There is a specific javascript methods to do this. [See this.](http://hspinfo.wordpress.com/2008/01/12/call-parent-windows-javascript-function-from-child-window/)

Comment: Sarfraz, your link no longer works. Please add relevant code to your answers and use links only for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a modal popup type container which will make communication simpler and give you more control of the data. It'll also work flawlessly even if the client has any sort of popup blocker (which most do by default).

It's easy to build from scratch and there are also many jquery plugins that make it even simpler.